# I'm new to using objects and classes. How do I print from within a user created class?

Tags: java, class, printing

I've created a class which is used by program which rolls a dice object 6 times. My problem is in my printStats() method as I'm not sure how to print the stats back to the main class. Specifically I am getting two errors and both say "expect return statement." Here is my class called Dice.

/*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

  class Dice{

Random rnd=new Random();
int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0;

String roll(){
    int a = rnd.nextInt(5);
    if(a == 0){
        count1++;
        return "1";
        }
    if(a == 1){
        count2++;
        return "2";
        }
    if(a ==2){
        count3++;
        return "3";
        }
    if(a == 3){
        count4++;
        return "4";
        }
    if(a == 4){
        count5++;
        return "5";
        }
    if(a == 5){
        count6++;
        return "6"; 
        }
    }
int printStats(){
        System.out.println("1:" + count1);
        System.out.println("2:" + count2);
        System.out.println("3:" + count3);
        System.out.println("4:" + count4);
        System.out.println("5:" + count5);
        System.out.println("6:" + count6);
    }

void reset(){
    count1 = 0;
    count1 = 0;
    count3 = 0;
    count4 = 0;
    `enter code here`count5 = 0;
    count6 = 0;
            }

            }
```

Comment: expect return statement is its way of telling you that youve declared a function which is currently not returning a value.. printStats meets that and it is possible that String roll does as (for the compiler) not every path through the function necessarily has a return value

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that your `roll()` method doesn't have a `return` for every possible execution path.

Now, you and I know that your logic guarantees one of the `if` statements will be `true`, and you'll return one of those, but because all of your `return` statements are within `if` statements, it won't compile.

There are three easy fixes.

1. Change your list of `if` statements to a big `if-else` structure, and simply change `if(a==5)` to the last `else`.
2. Use a `switch` statement, and use case 0-4, with 5 being default.
3. Just add `return "";` at the end of the current method, outside any `if` statement.

---

And for your `printStats()` method, you just need to change the return type to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't ever duplicate code like you did here - if you can write it much more elegantly using for loops:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    Random rnd=new Random();
    int[] count = new int[6];

    String roll(){
        int a = rnd.nextInt(6);
        count[a]++;
        return (a+1) + ""; // By the way, why do you bother returning 
                           // a string ? or any value at all ?
    }

    void printStats(){
        for(int i=0; i<count.length; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ":" + count[i]);
        }
    }

    void reset(){
        for(int i=0; i<count.length; i++){
            count[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Second, when you declare a method like: `int printStats()` it means that this method should return an int, since it doesn't - you are getting a compilation error.

Third, if you want this code to actually run - you should add a `main` method, for example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dice dice = new Dice();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            dice.roll();
        }
        dice.printStats();
        dice.reset();
        //etc
    }
```

Forth (and last), pay attention that if you want potentially to get 6 different random integers you should declare:

```
int a = rnd.nextInt(6);// returns an int in the range [0-5]
```

not:

```
int a = rnd.nextInt(5);
```

Comment: If I'm attempting to replicate a 6 sided die then I need six possibilities. As it is 0-5 inclusive I have a total of six possible integers that it could be. If I use 6 instead of 5 then I have a total of 7 possible numbers, correct?

Comment: @Berylthranox The first part of your statement is correct: you'll have 0-5 inclusive  this means 6 values: [0,1,2,3,4,5] so you can use these six values, only when you want to display them you'll have to do `+1`

Comment: Ah, ok. I was opposite in my thinking. Pardon my poor formatting here as well. I've only just discovered this site so I'm not quite used to posing questions. Aside from that I was aware that I could reformat most of my code to avoid repetition but I wanted to understand the interaction of a class and the methods within it before I tried to introduce an array. I was returning a string when I should have been printing the outcome of the dice roll.

Answer (score 0):

The methods signature indicates it will return a primitive int.  The class fails to compile because the compiler realizes the method does not return an int and throws the compilation error you receive.

A return type is specified within a method signature after its scope and before the method name.  The return type indicates the type of the primitive or object the method will return when called.  If no object is returned by a method, a return type of void is used.

In this case, the method should not return anything, which is indicated by specifying a return type of `void` in the method's signature.

```
   void printStats(){
        System.out.println("1:" + count1);
        System.out.println("2:" + count2);
        System.out.println("3:" + count3);
        System.out.println("4:" + count4);
        System.out.println("5:" + count5);
        System.out.println("6:" + count6);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `roll()` method contains a path that doesn't execute a `return` statement (ie when a<0 or a>5 then none of the `if` conditions would be `true`) - even though logically this can never happen, the compiler doesn't know how to infer that.

Your `printStats()` method is declared with return type `int`, but never returns any value.